# How to edit the Label Text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Label or Div anything in html

```
<label id="userId" class="normalWeight editInfo"></label>
```

When page load, i am assigning the value to that id

```
document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = allInfo.details.userId;
```

When i click the edit button, that is text will be editable. and then i will change the text and store into server. How to do this concept

I want like that. without using textbox. Is it possible?[image]

Comment: Maybe you should change `userId` in your javascript code to `userName`, which is the id of the label in your html? :)

Comment: What "edit" button?  You haven't shown us anything other than a `<label>` control - which (as you appear to realise) is not an "editable" control as far as the user is concerned.  It appears that you are asking us to write you the code to create, display and save the details from a textbox

Comment: I want edit and save without using textbox. It will be in label itself

Comment: [Please see this help about how to reply to comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) so that the person you're replying to gets a notification.  The `<label>` element in HTML simply has no ability to allow users to edit - that is what `<input type="text">` is for. You will need to "swap" with a hidden textbox as Kami says in their answer

Answer (score 1):

The label has id of `userName` and you are searching for `userId`.

Try

```
document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = allInfo.details.userId;
```

To allow editing, you should add a hidden textbox, that will be toggled when you click the edit button.

Assign this the value on load

```
document.getElementById('userName_Edit').value = allInfo.details.userId;
```

Then toggle this to visible, and hide the label.

```
document.getElementById('userName').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('userName_Edit').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: If you edit the question and make it working, it's not a problem anymore, and can't help other users.

Comment: @user12345789101112131415161718 I reread the question, the op asked something completly differnt.

Comment: We are using readonly in textboxes, i want like that. When i click the edit button, readonly will be false for the span or div or label

Comment: @Mohaideen Your question does not suggest anything of this nature. To remove an attribute from an element simply use the remove attibute function - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp. In this case it would be something like : `document.getElementById('userName_ReadOnlyBox').removeAttribute('readonly')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` and the `contenteditable` attribute.
Something like this?

```
function edit_label () {
    var l = document.getElementById('userID');
    if(this.innerHTML == 'Edit') {
        this.innerHTML = 'Save';//we set the button's value to 'save'
        l.removeAttribute("contentEditable");
    }
    else {
        this.innerHTML = 'Edit';//we set the button's value to 'edit'
        l.setAttribute("contentEditable", false);

        //Here you should use ajax to send the data.
        var data = l.innerHTML;//this will be sent
    }
}
document.getElementById('edit_button').onclick = edit_label;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uwaVL/

You should learn ajax before use it.
Ajax tutorial in w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP